# "ДевчОнки" или "девчЁнки"?

Tags: орфография, суффиксы

Как правильно писать слово "девчонки" и аналогичные слова?

Comment: как правильно писать девченки или девчонки?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Правильно писать "девчОнки". Буква О в существительных пишется в следующих суффиксах:

- "-ок" (пирож**о**к, порош**о**к, крюч**о**к);
- "-онок" (галч**онок**, мыш**онок**);
- "-онк(а)" (девч**онка**, деньж**онк**и).

Answer (score 6):

В суффиксах и окончаниях существительных после шипящих и Ц пишется О под ударением, Е без ударения. СобачОнка - речЕнька, холщОвый - кольцЕвой, но дирижЁр, массажЁр - суффикс *-ёр-.*